# What is the meaning of 'semantic' in "semantic HTML"?

Tags: html

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics) it is described as follow:

> Semantics (from Ancient Greek: σημαντικός sēmantikós, "significant")[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics)[a] is the linguistic and philosophical study of meaning in language, programming languages, formal logics, and semiotics. It is concerned with the relationship between signifiers—like words, phrases, signs, and symbols—and what they stand for in reality, their denotation.

In the Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) there are some semantic elements. Can I say, that the semantics of the element describes their purpose?

Comment: Yes, these elements has it's own meaning. E.g. `<footer>` purpose is to contain page footer

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML), that explained it better:

> Semantic HTML is the use of HTML markup to reinforce the semantics, or meaning, of the information in webpages and web applications rather than merely to define its presentation or look. Semantic HTML is processed by traditional web browsers as well as by many other user agents. CSS is used to suggest its presentation to human users.

Answer (score 1):

A semantic element clearly describes its meaning to both the browser and the developer.

Examples of non-semantic elements: `<div>` and `<span>` - Tells nothing about its content.

Examples of semantic elements: `<form>, <table>,` and `<article>` - Clearly defines its content.

read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

HTML Semantics elements are used to clearly describe their meanings both for human and machine. It is useful -

1. make the code easier to read
2. increased accessibility
3. consistent code.

Most common semantic elements are  etc